# chaining asynchronous operations before writing to client (python - tornado)

Tags: python, tornado

In a simple async case, handler might look like:

```
@tornado.web.authenticated
@tornado.web.asynchronous
def post(self):
    AsyncHTTPClient().fetch("http://api.example.com/", self.on_post_response)

def on_post_response(self, response):
    self.render("template.html", status=response.error)
```

However, I have come to a point when I need to perform two async operations (fetching remote rest api, and then sending mail with the results) before returning to the client.

I wonder if there is a "buit-in" way to do this, e.g. by adding callbacks to a queue (like `ioloop.add_callback`) or do I have to compose a custom object which will manage those tasks and their state and call it from `post`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered the following approach?

```
@tornado.web.authenticated
@tornado.web.asynchronous
def post(self):
    async_fetch(..., self._on_fetch_response)

def _on_fetch_response(self, response):
    async_mail(response, self._on_mail_response)

def _on_mail_response(self, response):
    self.render(...) # render() automatically calls self.finish()
```

Or using [tornado.gen](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/gen.html):

```
@asynchronous
@gen.engine
def post(self):
    fetch_response = yield gen.Task(async_fetch, ...)
    mail_response = yield gen.Task(async_mail, ...)
    self.render(...)
```

Comment: can you help defining the async_mail then, it seems as if this is the actual help I need ;-), is adding @asynchronous decorator makes every function async?

Comment: The `async_email()` was just a fictional example, see [tornadomail](https://github.com/equeny/tornadomail) for asynchronous SMTP client. The @asynchronous decorator makes the request handler method itself asynchronous, but the code inside the handler still blocks unless it explicitly supports non-blocking execution, e.g. via callback parameter. Thus you need special versions of IO libraries (mail, http, database) to take advantage of asynchronousness. The `gen.Task` is just syntactic sugar for the same thing.