# what does @tornado.web.asynchronous decorator mean?

Tags: python, tornado

1. If code didn't use this decorator, is it non-blocking?
2. Why this name is asynchronous, it means add decorator let code asynchronous?
3. Why @tornado.gen always use with @tornado.web.asynchronous together?

Comment: this looks like a list of wonderful things to search for on google.

Comment: searched, but lots of different answers, totally confused which one is correct

Answer (score 22):

`@tornado.web.asynchronous` [prevents the the `RequestHandler` from automatically calling `self.finish()`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.asynchronous). That's it; it just means Tornado will keep the connection open until you manually call `self.finish()`.

1. Code not using this decorator can block, or not. Using the decorator doesn't change that in any way.
2. As @Steve Peak said, you use the decorator for asynchronous requests, e.g. database retrieval.
3. Updated for Tornado 3.1+: If you use `@gen.coroutine`, you don't need to use `@asynchronous` as well. The older `@gen.engine` interface still requires `@asynchronous`, I believe.

Comment: The link to the tornado docs is broken. I'm guessing it's something similar to http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html ?

Comment: It seems that after your GET/POST is finished(coroutine is finished) the request is automatically finished when use @tornado.gen.coroutine as the decorator.
while using asynchronous, you must call self.finish()

Answer (score 5):

1. Answered here: [asynchronous vs non-blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625493/asynchronous-vs-non-blocking)
2. Think of it like this. When you need to make a request to say a database or another url to retrieve data you do not want to block your tornado IO. So the `@tornado.web.asynchronous` will allow the IO to handle other requests while it waits for the content to load (ex. database or url).
3. They are simular. You most likely will use `@tornado.web.asynchronous`.

   - Read more here: http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/gen.html
   - Example: [chaining asynchronous operations before writing to client (python - tornado)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377902/chaining-asynchronous-operations-before-writing-to-client-python-tornado)

Answer (score 0):

`@tornado.web.asynchronous` is essentially a just a marker you put on a handler method like `get()` or `post()` that tells the framework that it shouldn't call `finish()` automatically when the method returns, because it contains code that is going to set up `finish()` to be called at a later time.