# Really confusing about @tornado.web.asynchronous

Tags: python, tornado

When should we add this decorator ? what is the benefits of adding this decorator ? what's the differences between with tornado.gen?

I will be very appreciate if anyone could give me some details

Comment: possible duplicate of [what does @tornado.web.asynchronous decorator mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14582415/what-does-tornado-web-asynchronous-decorator-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@asynchronous` is a promise to call `self.finish()` instead of letting the request be finished automatically. This allows you to use asynchronous operations via callbacks.

`@gen.coroutine` (and `@gen.engine`, which is mostly obsolete) give the `yield` keyword special meaning, allowing you to use asynchronous operations via Futures and Tasks.

Use `@gen.coroutine` when you use the `yield` keyword, and `@asynchronous` when you use callbacks. In Tornado 3.0 it was sometimes necessary to use both together (and put `@asynchronous` first), but since Tornado 3.1 there is no reason to do so and you should only use one or the other.