# tornado redirect timing out

Tags: python, webserver, tornado

I am trying to add some user authentication to a web app i've build so im using resources provided by tornado here (http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/security.html)

how ever it times out unless i purposely mismatch my loginhandler and redirect (/login) in which case i then get a 404.

i have provided my code i have stripped some bits out down to the bare basics as the problem is somewhere here. but im not sure where. any help would be grand

```
import os    
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.websocket
from tornado.options import options, define


# Define available options
define("port", default=8888, type=int, help="run on the given port")

PORT = 8888

class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get_current_user(self):
        return self.get_secure_cookie("user")

class MainHandler(BaseHandler): 

    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):

        # Send our main document
        if not self.current_user:
            self.redirect("/login")
            return

        self.render("index.html")

class LoginHandler(BaseHandler):

    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
        self.write('<html><body><form action="/login" method="post">'
                   'Name: <input type="text" name="name">'
                   '<input type="submit" value="Sign in">'
                   '</form></body></html>')

    def post(self):
        self.set_secure_cookie("user", self.get_argument("name"))
        self.redirect("/")        

class TornadoWebServer(tornado.web.Application):
    ' Tornado Webserver Application...'
    def __init__(self):

        #Url to its handler mapping.
        handlers = [(r"/", MainHandler),
                    (r"/login", LoginHandler),
                    (r"/images/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": "web/images"}),
                    (r"/js/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": "web/js"}),
                    (r"/style/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": "web/style"})]

        #Other Basic Settings..
        settings = dict(
            cookie_secret="set_this_later",
            login_url="/login",
            template_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "web"),
            static_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static"),
            xsrf_cookies=True,
            debug=True)

        #Initialize Base class also.
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers, **settings)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    #Tornado Application
    print("Initializing Tornado Webapplications settings...")
    application = TornadoWebServer()

    # Start the HTTP Server
    print("Starting Tornado HTTPServer on port %i" % PORT)
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(PORT)

    # Get a handle to the instance of IOLoop
    ioloop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()

    # Start the IOLoop
    ioloop.start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using the @tornado.web.asynchronous decorator on your get requests removing this will fix the problem or if you need it you can call self.finish() after your write command.

you can find out more about this decorator here [what does @tornado.web.asynchronous decorator mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14582415/what-does-tornado-web-asynchronous-decorator-mean)

here is an example using self.finish on the login handlder

```
class LoginHandler(BaseHandler):

@tornado.web.asynchronous
def get(self):
    self.write('<html><body><form action="/login" method="post">'
               'Name: <input type="text" name="name">'
               '<input type="submit" value="Sign in">'
               '</form></body></html>')
    self.finish()

def post(self):
    self.set_secure_cookie("user", self.get_argument("name"))
    self.redirect("/")
```